# Error in Script. Command find is skipping folders with space character

Tags: bash, find

I need a script that counts the files in a directory (and sub). I've taken the followed script, and changed it to my need.

It works like it should, except for folders with space characters. I'm pretty sure I'm missing quotes anywhere, but can't figure it out yet.

#### Additional Informations

- Linux 2.6.22.19-0.4-default (this server is not in a productive environment anymore.)
- GNU find version 4.2.31
- I'm not able to rename the directories.

#### Example Directory Structure

```
.
..
01_infos
02_sent
03_inbox
04_public and private
197.
145.
329.
13.
```

#### Script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Write a script that will count the number of files in each of your subdirectories.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2001 nixCraft project <http://cyberciti.biz/fb/>
# This script is licensed under GNU GPL version 2.0 or above
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This script is part of nixCraft shell script collection (NSSC)
# Visit http://bash.cyberciti.biz/ for more information.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

START=$HOME

# change your directory to command line if passed
# otherwise use home directory
[ $# -eq 1 ] && START=$1 || :

if [ ! -d $START ]
then
        echo "$START not a directory!"
        exit 1
fi

# use find command to get all subdirs name in DIRS variable
DIRS=$(find "$START" -type d)

# loop thought each dir to get the number of files in each of subdir
for d in $DIRS
do
        echo "$d directory has $(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*\.' -type f | wc -l) files" || :
done
```

#### output

```
./01_infos directory has 1 files
./02_sent directory has 9 files
./03_inbox has 4 files
find: ./04_public: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just this?

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '/bin/echo -n "{}"; find "{}" -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*\." -type f | wc -l; ' \;
```

The output is not as sugary, but it doesn't require a script and it works for directories with spaces, as well as other non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: except for newlines, see below.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some double quotes (**always put double quotes around variable substitutions `$foo` and command substitutions `$(foo)`**, unless you know why you can safely leave them off and need to leave them off). But that's not the whole of the problem.

> `if [ ! -d $START ]`

should be `if [ ! -d "$START" ]`.

> `DIRS=$(find "$START" -type d)`

At this point, `DIRS` contains name of the start directory and its subdirectories recursively, with newlines in between. So if you have any directory name that contains a newline, you've lost: it's impossible to know which newlines came from a directory name and which were separators. If you know that there are no newlines in file names, you can parse the output of `find`, but how would you know?

By the way, it's ok to not have double quotes around `$(…)` here because this is a variable assignments, and substitutions in assignments are implicitly protected. However, note that <s>`export DIRS=$(…)`</s> is not similarly protected. Best to use quotes unless you're fluent in shell scripting and so are all the people who will maintain your script.

> `for d in $DIRS`

This is where you lose: you want to split `$DIRS` into words, so you can't put double quotes, but you need double quotes because `$DIRS` has all the elements concatenated together and the file names inside spaces would be separators if you leave them unquoted.

---

Usually, when you use `find`, you should make it invoke the processing command, with the `-exec` option. Unless you have tight controls on the file names, don't parse the output of `find`: it's ambiguous.

```
find "$START" -type d -exec sh -c '
    echo "$0 directory has $(find "$0" -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*\\." -type f -printf \\n | wc -l) files whose name ends with ."
' {} \;
```

Note again in the embedded `find` command that if you parse the output of `find`, your count will be off if any file name contains a newline.

Comment: The last command will not work though, since you forgot to change `$d` to `{}` and then it still it does not work for counting newlines. `find` receives them properly, but it looks like its regex engines don't like it and the newline breaks the matching. Using `-path "*\\."` makes it work.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx That was a copy-pasto, thanks, I forgot to change `$d` into `$0` (not `{}`! That would be non-portable and impossible to quote properly). I kept the regexp as it was in the question. Hmmm, so this particular regexp does exclude file names containing newlines, meaning that `-print | wc -l` would actually work in the inner `find`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, while `{}` does with no extra quoting. For portability, I see no other way than to split it up with `xargs`.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx Make sure you copied properly. I tested it, and the counts came out right. What error do you observe?

Comment: it returns a 0 count for my newlined folder.

Comment: visible here: http://paste.debian.net/177656

Answer (score -2):

You have a classic quoting mistake. Fix the for loop to look like this:

```
for d in "$DIRS"
```

Alternatively you could feed it `find`'s output directly, eg.:

```
find "$START" -type d | while read d
do # and so on...
```

As an aside, the `|| :` bit is completely redundant, since `echo` always has a return value of 0.

Comment: `"$DIRS"` is no good: the `for` loop body will run only once, on the concatenation of all the directory names. `while read d` should be `while IFS= read -r d`, and that will still choke on directory names containing newlines.

Comment: nice catch and seems that read can't take -d$'\0'.

Comment: Most shells can't handle null characters. Zsh can, and has a number of other advantages besides, but it's rarely installed by default.